# the request is invalid?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-routing

Bit of a asp.net mvc noob , I am trying to pass in a string as an argument for my Web API controller:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    public string Get(string arg)
    {
        return "othervalue";
    }

}
```

I tried to add another route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default2",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{arg}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", arg = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

So I want to keep both Get methods and use the Get with the arg parameter so I can pass in a string. So when I try to hit this url 'api/values/jjhjh' in my browser I get this error:

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.String Get(Int32)' in 'stackOverflowWebApi.Controllers.ValuesController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
```

Comment: can you show how you are trying to pass the string,  the link?

Comment: Have you tried making id nullable?

Comment: Route you are showing is of `Routeconfig` can you show us your `WebApiconfig`

Comment: Is your custom route placed before or after the default route in `RouteConfig`?

Comment: Why do you have a second default route that is doing the same thing that the first default route? That would not do anything. I suggest using route debugger to troubleshoot the routes you have to see why it is failing. See Phil Hackk's blog on Route debugger.

Answer (score 1):

The additional route you added was an MVC route, not a WebAPI route. WebAPI routes are not located in RouteConfig.cs by default, they are in WebApiConfig.cs. They look more like this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

The error you posted comes from not passing in any data at all. Give this a try instead:

```
public string Get(string id = null)
{
    return "othervalue";
}
```

Note that the parameter name is `id`, not `arg`, to make it match the optional route parameter. Also, defaulting it to null tells the binder that its okay to invoke this method when no data is passed.